# Payable functions in Metamask

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Please share your experience with Metamask/ether.js interaction. I created a payable function and as usual in Remix or Etherscan we can interact with a contract directly (we have inputs to put the value in there). When I deployed the same contract over hardhat, nothing happens. I cannot understand the steps to take. Let`s say I have a function:

```
function setGreeting(string memory _greeting) public payable {
    greeting = _greeting;
    require(msg.value == 5, "Need more money");
    }
}
```

After the deployment, Metamask does not ask any money and I understand that I missed something important. I have attached the deployment part and call the function in react template.

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling the contract?

Comment: @JulissaDC I have updated my description, please check. I'm just wondering, how to implement the field in the metamask wallet when user should add the eth with a calling function like Remix does.

Comment: If you want to also transfer a token to the user paying the function, you need to execute an approve transaction first and then call the payable method.

Comment: @user17732087 Welcome to StackExchange/Overflow. You can use three backticks (the key below the esc key) to declare the beginning and end of code. So something like ``` hello() ``` for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using React, I made a simliar project also using Metamask, and I used `eth_requestAccounts`, as you can see [in my code](https://github.com/JulzCryptoMyriad/JulzWidget/blob/4ba9d3e8c5926742f03e31d00c5eaa5ee5fad225/julzwidgetapp/src/components/PaymentComponent.js#L74), basically you call for the signer and wait until you have one:

```
        await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        await signer;
```

And then you need to call the contract with that signer, in my case I used `connect`, like this:

```
await contract.connect(signer).deposit(/*arguments*/, {value: ethdeposit});
```

This is what is going to prompt Metamask, you can check the full implementation on the link I sent. You can check more on how to use The Metamask provider [here](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#using-the-provider).